# Touchscreen Right Click

Tags: python, python-2.x, linux, touch

I have built a small script that provides touch screen right click context menu with long touch press in my ELAN touchscreen.
There is no need to remove your finger in order context menu to pop up.

System Specs: Debian 8 Sid, with XFCE and Nautilus as WM.

Some environments handle right clicks differently:

- Environments like XFCE and Thunar, right click is correctly injected in free space.
- Environments like Nautilus (i.e Caja, Nemo) right click is ignored.

  Raising context menu in Nautilus free / user space seems impossible due to the fact that Nautilus does not allow right click menu to pop up while you are pressing left click, and [you perform a kind of "drag"](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=634520). Although this is allowed when you select an item (file/folder) inside nautilus. To which I have found a solution to overcome this Nautilus limitation. I inject a right click while I long press the screen inside Nautilus space but it is a little bit ugly, as I temporary disable the screen, then I inject a right click, and then I enable the screen again.

  I wonder if there is a better way to overcome this Nautilus limitation.

Below you will find the currently nice working script, which in any case targets to provide context menu without finger release.

Remark : Bellow script works with ELAN TouchScreen and any other touchscreen that emits a BTN_TOUCH (code 330) event.

```
from evdev import InputDevice
import time
from pymouse import PyMouse
from threading import Timer
import subprocess


def rightclick():
    print "Right Click Timer Starting. Pressed Flag=", pressed
    timestop = time.time()
    endx, endy = m.position()  # Get the coordinates after time has elapsed
    deltatime = timestop - timestart
    if pressed == True and (abs(endx - startx) < 20) and (abs(endy - starty) < 20):
        print 'Timer Finished - Right Click to be injected. Pressed Flag:', pressed, 'Deltatime=', deltatime, ' Delta X:', abs(endx - startx), ' Delta Y:', abs(endy - starty)
    subprocess.check_call(['xinput', '--disable', 'ELAN Touchscreen'])
    m.press(endx, endy, 2)
    m.release(endx, endy, 2)
    subprocess.check_call(['xinput', '--enable', 'ELAN Touchscreen'])

dev = InputDevice('/dev/input/event10')  
# Run evtest to verify the correct ELAN event number and modify above line accordingly
print(dev)  # Print device information
m = PyMouse() #Register a pymouse object

# -------- Right Click Injection without finger relase (Code Begin)

pressed = False
for event in dev.read_loop():
    if event.type == 1 and event.code == 330 and event.value == 1: 
    #corresponds to BTN_TOUCH (330) event. value 1 means btn pressed down = screen pressed
        startx, starty = m.position()  
        # gets mouse current/starting position coordinates
        pressed = True
        timestart = time.time()
        t = Timer(1.0, rightclick) #register a timer of 1 second and call rightclick function when finished.
        t.start() # start the timer

    if event.type == 1 and event.code == 330 and event.value == 0: 
    #corresponds to BTN_TOUCH (330) up event. value 0 means btn up = screen not pressed = finger removed
    # Detecting finger release BTN_TOUCH (330); Value becomes 0.
        print "Finger removed ..."
        pressed = False
        t.cancel() #Cancel the timer and cancel right click injection if finger removed before 1 second (short press , equal to left click on touchscreens)

    if event.type == 3 and event.code == 47 and event.value == 1: 
    #Event ABS_MT_SLOT . This event gets value 1 when 2 fingers touch the screen.
    # Two fingers tap brings right click menu. 
        print "Two Finger tap..."
        x2, y2 = m.position()  # Get the pointer coordinates
        m.click(x2, y2, 2)
        print "Two Finger tap Right Click Injected..."

# --------  Right Click Injection without finger relase (Code End)
```

Comment: Does this work with regular mice? As a quick test on my Arch + Awesome install doesn't do anything...

Comment: No, works only with touch screens.

Comment: @GeorgeVasiliou please bear with us. You'll **eventually** get a review. As your code is very platform specific and _hard_ to test, you'll have to wait for users to get used to the modules you used.